# How do I upload full directory on FTP in python?

Tags: python, directory, ftp, ftplib

I have to upload a directory, with subdirectories and files inside, on a FTP server. But I can't seem to get it right. I want to upload the directory as it is, with it's subdirectories and files where they were.

```
ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect('host',port)
ftp.login('user','pass')
filenameCV = "directorypath"

for root,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(filenameCV):
    for files in filenames:
        print(files)
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + files, open(files,'rb'))
        ftp.quit()
```

Answer (score 18):

There are multiple problems with your code: First, the `filenames` array will only contain the actual filenames, not the entire path, so you need to join it with `fullpath = os.path.join(root, files)` and then use `open(fullpath)`. Secondly, you quit the FTP connection inside the loop, move that `ftp.quit()` down on the level of the `placeFiles()` function.

To recursively upload your directory, you have to walk through your root directories and at the same time through your remote directory, uploading files on the go.

Full example code:

```
import os.path, os
from ftplib import FTP, error_perm

host = 'localhost'
port = 21

ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect(host,port)
ftp.login('user','pass')
filenameCV = "directorypath"

def placeFiles(ftp, path):
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        localpath = os.path.join(path, name)
        if os.path.isfile(localpath):
            print("STOR", name, localpath)
            ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + name, open(localpath,'rb'))
        elif os.path.isdir(localpath):
            print("MKD", name)

            try:
                ftp.mkd(name)

            # ignore "directory already exists"
            except error_perm as e:
                if not e.args[0].startswith('550'): 
                    raise

            print("CWD", name)
            ftp.cwd(name)
            placeFiles(ftp, localpath)           
            print("CWD", "..")
            ftp.cwd("..")

placeFiles(ftp, filenameCV)

ftp.quit()
```

Comment: nice solution, I could use this almost from scratch